# Add the title 'Appendices' to the top of the page containing appendices

Tags: header-footer, titles, appendices

I want to have the word 'Appendices' at the top of the page containing appendices.

I have two columns of text, and there are various appendices labelled 'A   title here', 'B   title here', etc.

I want to have a simple main-title on the top of these that simple reads 'Appendices' (in slightly bigger font.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}
Refer to Appendix~\ref{append_a}.


\clearpage
\appendix
%% I want to have something here like \title{appendix}
\section{The first appendix}
\label{append_a}
Text here

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a minimal working example with `\documentclass{...}` and `\begin{document}...\end{document}` that shows your problem. I am pretty sure, that there are already questions concerning this topic

Comment: If you are referring to a header, you may want to have a look at the `fancyhdr` package.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need to create a command, but using one just looks better to me (more modular).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\newcommand{\appendixhead}%
{\centering\textbf{\huge Appendices}
\vspace{0.25in}}

\begin{document}
Refer to Appendix~\ref{append_a}.

\twocolumn[\appendixhead]
\appendix
\section{The first appendix}
\label{append_a}
Text here

\end{document}
```